# How to save a list of leads who opened a mailing to Salesforce?

Tags: leads, csv, data-migration

I'm feeding data to Salesforce through a CSV using APEX.

This works great to update the database, with new leads and updating lead information.

I'm interested on also transfering lists to Salesforce of contacts who opened a mailing or attended a certain event (basically behavioral data). In what format could this info be saved in Salesforce?

Comment: "contacts" meaning SFDC Contacts?  Regardless, CSV is the primary format used to upload via DataLoader or any of the Import Wizards

Comment: hi @crip1645 my question is once I import a CSV with a list of leads who "Attended Event X" for example. How can my salespeople see all the leads that "Attended Event X"? Should I create a campaign for all this people? Is there a way to log "Attended Event X" to each of these leads activity?

Answer (score 0):

*That would be crop1645, not crip1645 which sounds like a gangster from South Los Angeles  :-)*

When you import Leads for an event, normally you create a Campaign first and then the Lead Import wizard available on the Lead tab or at `Setup | Data Management | Import Leads` allows you to associate all imported Leads to that Campaign

However, as you have already imported the Leads, you need to assign the Leads to the Campaign 'Attended Event X'. Create a Campaign and then click Manage Members to select from the leads you imported to assign to the Campaign

You can then create Lead list views that show Leads for a particular campaign.